# How do I install a program to users' desktops?

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-7, uac

I am trying to create an installer for an app I have built. I am having trouble when trying to copy the program to users' desktops: When copying the program, I get an error:

> System Error. Code: 5. Access is denied.

I have tried running as administrator but nothing seems to work. When I copy the file to Program Files, it works fine, but when I try to copy to a user's desktop, I get the error message. My target platforms are Windows 7 and Windows 8.

Here is some of my code:

```
function GetCurrentUserName : String;
const
  cnMaxUserNameLen = 254;
var
  dwUserNameLen : DWORD;
begin
  dwUserNameLen := cnMaxUserNameLen-1;
  SetLength(sUserName, cnMaxUserNameLen);
  GetUserName(PChar(sUserName), dwUserNameLen);
  SetLength(sUserName, dwUserNameLen);
  Result := sUserName;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Source, Source2, Dest, Dest2: String;
begin
  Source := 'rusmar.bin';
  Dest := 'C:/Program Files/RusMarEstimatingModel.exe';
  if not CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), False)
    then RaiseLastOSError;
  GetCurrentUserName;
  Source := 'rusmar.bin';
  Dest := 'C:/Users/' + sUserName + '/Desktop/RusMarEstimatingModel.exe';
  if not CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), False)
    then RaiseLastOSError;
  label2.Show;
  timer1.Enabled := True;
end;
```

Comment: You should learn to format your posts.

Comment: sorry im also a noob to this website

Comment: can you help with my problem

Comment: Are you sure your app has access to the **source** file, rather than the **destination** file?  And why are you using a relative path to access the source file?  Always use absolute paths.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess it sees source fine since first copy succeeds.

Comment: This code is nowhere near an "installer". You should look at something like InnoSetup, which is free, and build an actual installer. You have hard-coded paths to files (at least one of which is totally wrong, BTW); there are API calls that would return the correct locations. InnoSetup will allow you to build an actual `Setup.exe` that will put files in proper locations, create shortcuts correctly, and make your life much simpler.

Comment: St John Russel, your best approach is to abandon this code and use InnoSetup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It's free, you can verry quickly make a basic insatller using its wizards, and if you want (later) tweak the installs with its built-in Pascal-like scripting language. You'll save yourself tons of time that you can spend on more interesting programming problems ;-)

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel called installers?

Comment: Copying EXE to desktop ? are you mad ? you should make a shortcut there! and in Program Files you have to make a folder, not to place EXe in the root. And where do you take paths from ? i do not have paths `C:\Users\ ` and `C:\Program Files\ ` one one of my Win7 box. Take ready-made installer, really. Like InnoSetup. Or NSIS. Or WiX. Or at least go www.torry.net and in Tools section look for some opensource installer - though their are mostly outdated but you still can read their sources and learn. Well, InnoSetup sources you can read too :-)

Comment: You may use SysInternals Process Monitor to check what you program actualyl does and what your system actually responds it. Maybe OS fails to correct your erroneous  "/" chars into proepr "\" chars. Or maybe there already exists that EXE on desktop and it is executing and can not be rewritten. Or whatever else.

Comment: I can second using Inno, it's very good, especially for Delphi developers because it features a Pascal scripting engine. It's also open source itself, and written in Delphi. http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether or not this is the problem, but that's just not how you get hold of the path to the logged on user's desktop. The path might well have that form, but in lots of situations it will not.

For example:

1. Older versions of Windows, e.g. XP.
2. Some future as yet unreleased version of Windows changes things.
3. The user moves their profile.
4. The machine uses a language other than English and Desktop is localized.

The correct way to do it is to use one of the functions that receives a `CSIDL` or a known folder ID. For example by passing `CSIDL_DESKTOP` to `SHGetSpecialFolderPath`.

The same goes for the program files folder which is `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES`.

Once you get this sorted, you may still get `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Obviously since you are copying to the desktop of the logged on user, you should have rights to that folder? Has anything interfered with security settings on that folder? Open the security settings dialog and look at the effective rights that you have in that folder. Does the file already exist and has it got an ACL that prohibits you writing over the file? Does it exist already and is read-only?

Comment: The code also tries to copy directly to `C:\Program Files\`, which will not be accessible either.

Comment: @Ken It will when run elevated. According to the Q the copy to Program Files succeeds, but the subsequent one fails.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan exactly my thoughts you just told.  But funny thing is, the moment i saw my word keyed by you, i instantly changed my mind. You know what ? despite he's saying "run as administrator" i suspect know he DOES NOT run elevated indeed. `c:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\ ` ;-)

Comment: However if he runs elevated or not should not matter. He does not pushes his EXE onto "All Users" desktop but to current user private desktop. Which should work with or without administrator grants. I guess the EXE is already there and is running or is locked by some other process. Procexp could show it of course... but  TS's code is so broken by its intentions, that i feel any attempt to help making that code work is a crime. It's like... well, like helping  kid to burn wet matches in the paper house.

Comment: @Arioch Hmm. I'd forgotten about virtualization. Don't see it so much these days. Quite plausible for D7 too. Nice to know that you judge things based on who writes them and think that it must be wrong if it's me writing! ;-)

Comment: Well, we'd better coin it like you're inspiring me :-D

Comment: the file isn't already on the desktop and i have all required access rights to copy to the desktop but it still doesn't copy. ill try the CSIDL and let you know if it solves the problem

Comment: SysInternals Process Monitor  to help you... to help you in this ominous deed